# Паттерн экспорта данных в xml из ms sql

Tags: c#, xml, sql-server

Есть БД ms sql (около 100 таблиц), необходимо некоторые данные экспортировать в XML строго определенного формата (есть XSD схема и документ с описанием), как наиболее оптимально и правильно поступить в данном случае? Пробовал использовать bcp, но со сложной xml (необязательные элементы, циклы и тд) это достаточно проблематично.

update: Данные берутся из нескольких таблиц

Comment: Хм. А что делать, если схема таблицы не ложится на xsd? Или этот вариант исключён?

Comment: Данные берутся из нескольких таблиц

Comment: "как наиболее оптимально" - наиболее оптимально не получится. можно либо оптимально, либо *не* оптимально.

Comment: @Dennis Можно по теме?

Comment: Можно посмотреть в сторону DataTable и его метод WriteXml. Т.е. создаете DataTable нужной Вам структуры, заполняете его данными и записываете в xml. Вот тут есть пример: https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.data.datatable.writexml%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Comment: А почему бы не воспользоваться xml-сериализацией?

Comment: @PowerStream можно подробнее или пример?

Comment: Разверну ответом, с примерами кода.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Для экспорта данных из БД в xml, можно воспользоваться сериализацией. Это самый простой путь.
Вот пример как это можно реализовать:

```
[XmlRoot(ElementName = "root")]
class TableRow
{
    [XmlElement(ElementName = "field1", Namespace = "http://unknown.org")]
    object field1 {get;set;}
    [XmlElement(ElementName = "field2", Namespace = "http://unknown.org")]
    object field2 {get; set;}
}
using (var bd = new MyEntity())
{
   var list = bd.Table1.ToList();
   XmlSerializer serial = new XmlSerializer(typeof(List<TableRow>));
   var f = File.Create("out.xml");
   serial.Serialize(f, list);
   f.Close()
}
```

Атрибутами класса/свойств, можно регулировать сериализацию полей как душе угодно.

Comment: А заполнять экземпляр класса в цикле или как это происходит? Допустим я создал автоматом класс с помощью `xsd.exe` на основе схемы, а как его заполнять? Допустим если в бд большой объем информации.

Comment: В примере я использовал ADO.NET. Я просто выгружаю таблицу методом ToList(). Который создает список List<TableRow>. Содержащий данные таблицы.
Большой объем информации это сколько? 1000 строк, 10000, 1кк? Таблицы объемом больше 100к строк, требуют другого подхода. Через SQL-запрос, получения курсора и построчного его считывания. Возможно даже разбиения результирующего xml на несколько файлов. И это будет все исключительно ручная работа.